# How to integrate FCM in a PhoneGap App

Tags: cordova, firebase, phonegap-build, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm trying to add FCM functionalities to my PhoneGap app: 
i've added   in my config.xml and i've got my google-services.json, but when i try to build my app, i have an error like this:

> *Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.     Searched Location:
> >     /project/src/debug/google-services.json
> >     /project/google-services.json*

Is there a way to resolve this problem? 
The .json file is at the same level of my config.xml file, in the www folder. 
Thanks for your interest.

Comment: which plugin you had used ?

Comment: **UPDATE**: after adding both cordova-plugin-fcm and cordova-plugin-fcm-config, my error has changed in "Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.> No matching client found for package name 'xxx' ", but my config.xml's id and package id of json file are matching. What's wrong? Do i have to place my json file in a specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

The files need to be alongside the www folder, problem is that Phonegap Build only lets you upload the contents of said folder, so you can't upload the files.

Fortunately there's something you can do; Build installs the plugins directly from npm, and plugins can work thought the whole project, so what you need is a plugin that copies the files [google-services.json, GoogleService-Info.plist] for you.

Most of the work has already been done: [cordova-plugin-fcm-config](https://github.com/stetro/cordova-plugin-fcm-config).

This plugin copies the required FCM configurations in the project root folders and Xcode project. It is used in combination with the great cordova-plugin-fcm plugin.
It wasn't built for this purpose but works wonderfully.

There's an added complexity though; since you can't upload plugins (you can only add a reference to it in your config.xml), and this plugin needs your own app configuration files, you'll have to:

Clone/Fork the plugin into your own repository.
Replace the configuration files.
Upload it somewhere Build can find.
Where do you upload it? That might be tricky. The infrastructure is built around the idea that plugins are for general purposes and can be configured in each project xml, so npm makes sense. But in this case your plugin will contain very specific data to your project, so uploading to npm would pollute the namespace in my opinion.

I don't know about you, but I have a paid account, so I publish the plugin in my own repository and submit as a private plugin. This is what I recommend.